# Corelation between money growth and inflation

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, data-request

I am looking for some thorough papers on relation between money supply and inflation in short and long run i.e. how and why money supply affect prices in short and long run?

I was trying to find some interesting papers on that topic, however i was unsuccessful thus i would be glad if you would help me with the task of find informations regarding this particular topic.

Comment: [Studies in the Quantity Theory of Money  Milton Friedman](http://0055d26.netsolhost.com/friedman/pdfs/other_academia/Palgrave.1987.c.pdf)

Comment: [The Contribution of Monetary History of the United States, 1867–1960 Michael Bordo](http://www.nber.org/chapters/c6734.pdf)

Comment: You might also want to read the original paper published by Friedman, the works by Keynes,  and the actions of Benjamin Strong

Comment: I should have just made an answer!  [A good book is The Forgotten Depression James Grant](http://www.amazon.com/The-Forgotten-Depression-Crash-Itself/dp/1451686455).   The book itself is more about corecting markets, but it is based on the 1921 crash.  It gives detailed examples on the effects money supply and inflation have on the real world and the problems it causes.

Comment: @lost Why don't you convert your comments into an answer, so it can be upvoted and marked as solved?